# Could not load file or assembly. A strongly-named assembly is required

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, .net-assembly

When i call an endpoint on my web api project, i get this error -

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Linq.Dynamic, Version=1.0.5840.25917, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. A strongly-named assembly is required. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044)

i cannot seem to sign this assembly-  System.Linq.Dynamic.dll with a strong name using Visual Studio 2017 (see attached image).

if i use the command line it seems to work, however using visual studio 2015, it doesn't seem to sign the dll with a strong name.

[image]

[image]

Comment: i am using a version from nuget (see attached)

Comment: I pulled down this package just now.  I got version 1.0.6132.35681.  It is strongly-signed.

Comment: This assembly has a Microsoft copyright, it however does not come from Microsoft.  That ought to make you a bit nervous.  [This github issue](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic/issues/72) suggests that the submitter is not really aware how to do this correctly.  Consider helping him.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time out to help with this. What about if i created a Post Build event in Visual Studio to sign the assembly?

Comment: Give up this package and switch to another, https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core which is much more actively maintained and has all necessary setup.

Comment: @lex-li thanks for that, i swapped the package round with System.Linq.Dynamic.Core and it worked seamlessly. I inherited legacy code which was using System.Linq.Dynamic and seems to work in an old project. But i couldn't get it to work in my newer solution, so this is a big help. Can you please add your suggestion to answer the question to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read [System.Linq.Dynamic.Core](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core) to see how many forks of `System.Linq.Dynamic` are there.

The openness allows you to choose another NuGet package which ships a strong named assembly for the project, and that solves the issue.

Hope one of the forks would grow and one day becomes the "upstream" :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar (same) error (different cause):

> Could not load file or assembly 'xx' or one of its dependencies. A
> strongly-named assembly is required. (Exception from HRESULT:
> 0x80131044)

It turned out that the Project ('xx') in my solution, that I referenced from another project was not set to build in Debug mode. When I selected Properties (F4) of the project ('xx') in Visual Studio, it turned out that the value for "Always Start When Debugging" was set to False.

I set it to True, and the error was resolved.